# PHP error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in [location]index.php on line 7

Tags: php, html, centos

i am sorta new to PHP, i mostly use HTML. I have made a PHP script. What the code should do is display a youtube video when i put the code. like this
"website.com/youtube.php?v=1010111" It would display the youtube video but
I keep on getting the error :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in [location]/index.php on
>   line 7

Here is the code:

```
<?php
if( $_GET["v"])
{
$matches = $_GET['v'];
 echo "Welcome ". $_GET['v']. "<br />";

 <html>

 <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/" </html><?php . $_GET['v'].  ?> <html>frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</html>     
exit();
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="GET">
Name: <input type="text" name="v" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you switch out of PHP, use `?>`; when you wswitch back to PHP again, use `<?php`

Comment: just add `?>` before `<html>` on line 7 and switch it back again with `<?php` before `exit();`..

Comment: Use this `<?php
if( $_GET["v"])
{
$matches = $_GET['v'];
 echo "Welcome ". $_GET['v']. "<br />";

 echo'<html>

 <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/" </html>'.$_GET['v'].' <html>frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</html>';     
exit();
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="GET">
Name: <input type="text" name="v" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write `?>` when you want to stop writing PHP code.

At line 7, ou have `<html>`, just write `?>` before that html tag.

Comment: Use this `<?php
if( $_GET["v"])
{
$matches = $_GET['v'];
 echo "Welcome ". $_GET['v']. "<br />";

 echo'<html>

 <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/" </html>'.$_GET['v'].' <html>frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</html>';     
exit();
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="GET">
Name: <input type="text" name="v" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>`